# Get value from parameter Map where key is an ID

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I can't figure out how to get a value from a map passed as a parameter to a Mybatis xml.
I've got a map like

```
key   value
 42   0.66
 44   0.48
 18   1
```

It is passed to mybatis as a parameter.
I want to get a value from it, but I don't know how to access specific  tuple.
Usually if I pass a map as a param it has string keys and there is no problem to fetch a value just typing

```
someId = #{paramsMap.id, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
```

The goal is to fetch a value buy filtering map using location_id from sql
something like

```
someId = #{paramsMap."sql_select_result.location_id", jdbcType=NUMERIC}
```

Is there a way to do so?

Or as an alternative is there a way to use parameterMap as a subselect result like

```
select location_id, currency_ratio from (#{paramsMap.id, jdbcType=NUMERIC}) currencyMap where location_id = 18
```

Hope my description is clear enough.

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you what to do. I need to know better what you need to answer your question. Do you need to convert value stored in database to some other value? Why do you need to have this conversion in mapper? Why the option to have a table that stores `location_id->ratio` in a table does not work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to get value from a map that is passed as a parameter to mybatis' sql template and then get a value from it by a key which is calculated in sql during script execution.  'location_id->ratio' doesn't work in my case because it can't be accessed directly and a stored function needs to be called and it makes the whole script to execute damn slow (56s vs 3s).